# Publisher/Subscriber with changing subscriptions during loop

Tags: c++, loops, publish-subscribe

This is more of a general design query I had. I have implemented a publish / subscribe pattern by maintaining a list of subscribers. When an event to publish occurs, I loop through the subscribers and push the event to each one, of them in turn.

My problem occurs when due to that publication, somewhere in the depth of the software, another component or event the described component decide to unsubscribe themselves. By doing so, they invalidate my iterator and cause crashes.

What is the best way to solve this? I have been thinking of wrapping the whole publication loop into a try catch block, but that means some subscribers miss the particular subscription upon which someone unsubscribed, and seems a bit over the top. Then I tried feeding it back, e.g. I turned the void publish call into a bool publish call that returns true when the subscriber wants to be deleted, which works for that case, but not if another subscriber unsubscribes. Then I am thinking to "cache" unsubscription requests somewhere and release them when the loop is done, but that seems a bit overkill. Then I am thinking of storing the iterator as a class member, so that I can manipulate the iterator from outside, but that gets messy (say you unsubscribe subscriber 1, iterator is pointed at 2, and the container is a vector - then the iterator would have to be decremented). I think I might prefer one of the latter two solutions, but both seem not ideal.

Is this a common problem? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: If your application is multithreaded you need to protect the list in some way; if not, I can't imagine the need to unsibscribe _another_ subscriber. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Well say one subscriber manages all sorts of applications and upon some event he subscribes and unsubscribes them... it is not that he himself unsubscribes, it is more that he e.g. calls the managed items destructor, which then unsubscribes itself, but that comes down to the same thing as the iterator is still pointing at the manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either disallow subscription operations during publication, or you could use an appropriate data structure to hold your subscription list, or both.

Assuming that you keep your subscribers in a `std::list`, you could run your loop thus:

```
for(iterator_type it = subs.begin(); it != subs.end(); ) {
    iterator_type next = it;
    ++next;
    it->notifier();
    it = next;
}
```

That way, if  the current item is removed, you still have a valid iterator in `next`. Of course, you still can't allow arbitrary removal (what if `next` is removed?) during publication.

To allow arbitrary removal, mark an item as invalid and defer its list removal until it is safe to do so:

```
... publication loop ...
dontRemoveItems = true;
for(iterator_type it = subs.begin(); it != subs.end(); ++it) {
    if(it->valid)
        it->notifier();
}
std::erase(std::remove_if(...,, IsNotValid),...);
dontRemoveItems = false;
```

elsewhere,

```
... removal code:
if(dontRemoveItems) item->valid = false;
else subs.erase(item);
```

Comment: I like the latter approach as well.  One thing to watch for in C++ is that if a thread is removing one item while another thread is removing its predecessor, the item may get erroneously re-added to the list.  In a garbage-collected language, this wouldn't be a problem since the item would be recognized as dead and would be re-deleted the next time something iterated the list.  In C++, though, there could be trouble if the item were re-added to the list after the memory for it was deleted.  Consequently, one should probably restrict deletion to a single thread.

Comment: I failed to consider multi-threading at all as I wrote my answer. Caveats apply.